# probability puzzle with dice

Tags: probability

The game board has 12 spaces.  A goose starts on space 7, and a hunter on space 1. On each game turn a 6-sided die is rolled. On a result of 1 to 4, the goose moves that many spaces forward. On a result of 5 or 6, the hunter moves that many spaces forward. The goose wins if it reaches space 12 (the final roll does not have to be exact, moving past space 12 is ok). The hunter wins if she catches the goose, in other words reaches the same or a higher space.

What are the probabilities of winning for the goose and the hunter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every position is a pair $(h,g)$, the coordinates of the hunter and goose.
Let $P(h,g)$ the probability the goose wins starting from the position $P(h,g)$. Then
$$
P(h,g)=\frac16\bigg(P(h,g+1)+P(h,g+2)+P(h,g+3)+P(h,g+4)+P(h+5,g)+P(h+6,g)\bigg)
$$
This, combined with the base cases
$$
P(h,g)=1\qquad\text{when }g\ge 12
$$
$$
P(h,g)=0\qquad\text{when }h\ge g
$$
allows you to calculate $P(h,g)$ for all values of $(h,g)$, starting with the simpler cases (the ones closer to the end of the game), and working backward to the starting position $P(1,7)$. Otherwise, this is just brute force. Not that much brute force, though, since there are less than $20$ positions (the goose can only ever be on spaces $7$ through $11$, the hunter on $1,6,7,11$).

Comment: Thanks for modeling the problem. But how should I work backwards from the base cases? Could you write down the first iteration?

Comment: It's done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following Python code calculates the probability of the hunter to win:

```
def func(hunter,goose,num):
    if hunter >= goose:
        return 1.0/6**num
    if goose >= 12:
        return 0.0
    probability = 0.0
    for val in [1,2,3,4]:
        probability += func(hunter,goose+val,num+1)
    for val in [5,6]:
        probability += func(hunter+val,goose,num+1)
    return probability

print func(1,7,0)
```

Yields the following outcome:

```
0.387217078189
```

So the probability of the hunter to win is approximately $38.72\%$.

Comment: What about people that don't know the Python language?  How are they supposed to know what this code does?  For example, what does the val in [1,2,3,4]: line do?  What is the scope of the variable called probability?  Is it a local or a global?  How deep (how many levels) of recursion are required?  This code is not self documenting.

Comment: @David: This is one solution out of several possible solutions. If you see a concrete flaw in this solution, then please point it out. Stop searching for otherwise problems due to the previous comments I have made with regards to you **non-deterministic** solution. This question in specific (and this website in general) is **not** about specific programming languages, nor is it about giving agnostic solution in all possible languages.

Comment: @David: Had the question been tagged *Python* on Stack-Overflow, then your comment would have made sense. Otherwise, it just seems like some sort of attempt to bug me instead of referring to the conceptual problem that I have pointed out with regards to your general method of solving this question.

Comment: My point is your code is not readable.  If I want to port it to some other language I would not know how to do so to verify it cuz I do not know Python code.  Good code will have documentation in it describing anything that needs clarification.  You have NONE.

Comment: @David: Porting to other languages??? How many times to I have to emphasize that this question (and in fact, this entire website) is not targeting a specific programming language. The whole point of this mathematical problem is to provide some sort of solution, accurate if possible (and in this case, it **IS** possible). This is not a programming contest. And BTW, I would strongly recommend that you don't blame other answers for "unreadable code" while you have not even bothered to provide **any code** in your programmatic solution!!!

Comment: You are wrong.  I gave pseudo-code which is high level explanation of my algorithm which can be implemented in just about any high level computer language.  My solution is not a "black box" solution. I described what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a computer simulation of $10$ million decisions once and got the following results:

Goose winning probability:  $61.25637$%

Hunter winning probability: $38.74363$%

Easy simulation program to write in any general purpose computer language having a random number generator.  No point is showing the code here cuz since it is so simple and the person who asked the original question did not ask to see it.  I just grab a random integer number from $1$ to $6$ and "move" that many spaces, checking for a winner and until I get a winner.  I repeat that decision $10$ million times which is an arbitrary number but chosen as a balance of speed and accuracy.  I could have chosen $100,000$ or $1$ billion but there is not much advantage to doing so.

Also note that an interesting variation of this question is if you start the goose at position $6$ instead of position $7$, the probability of the goose winning becomes very close to a coin flip ($50$/$50$).  I get about $50.3$% in favor of the goose ($49.7$% for the hunter).

Comment: Why would you implement a random simulation if you can implement an exact simulation of all possible cases (of which, by the way, there are much less than $10$ million)?

Comment: Cuz it is late here and my solution requires less thought and effort and should be almost 100% accurate compared to counting.

Comment: You did not even bother to publish your solution here, which makes this answer rather useless IMO. Users here are typically looking for a **proved-method**, not just a numerical answer (let alone the fact that your numerical answer is a probabilistic one, which was not asked for in this case, and in fact - is not even needed with regards to the question at hand, which has a simple, deterministic and non-probabilistic solution).

Comment: Also because computers are fast and these $10$ million decisions are more than enough to get an excellent approximation.

Comment: Also, please don't take offense, but "it is late here and my solution requires less thought and effort" is not much of a good excuse for such answer. In fact, it's a good excuse for **not publishing** this answer in the first place.

Comment: My methodology is there is usually a "right" way and an easy way.  If the easy way (in this case simulation) yields an excellent approximation (which it does), then that is good enough.  Trying to count the correct number of cases by someone not good in math (generally speaking) can lead to errors so my method is more "foolproof" to someone with basic programming skills.  Also there are some problems that cannot be counted easily and "require" simulation.  The person who asked this question did not ask for a proof, just for the probabilities which I gave so the answer is valid.

Comment: `someone not good in math` should consider it carefully before answering any questions here!!! I do not argue the fact that for this specific question, counting all the possible combinations is a tedious and difficult task. I certainly agree that a computer program is the correct means for solving the specific question at hand. But I disagree about solving it by running a large amount of random data, when you can run a small accurate **full coverage** simulation of the problem.

Comment: In addition, even if a random simulation **was** a reasonable solution in this case, you would still need to post your code and not just the result. But again, one can easy run a simulation to cover all cases, so any solution of running random data is simply not good enough.

Comment: `No point is showing the code here cuz since it is so simple and the person who asked the original question did not ask to see it`, doesn't make your answer any better (again, IMO). I don't normally down-vote answers here, but if I were you then I would expect to see down-votes on this answer at some point (so please don't go down-voting my answer if you see them). Good night.

Comment: To summarize this: A probabilistic solution is legitimate only when **the computational time** of the exact solution is extremely long, NOT when **the time it takes you to think** of a solution is extremely long.

Comment: I disagree.  For a simple problem like this, it is an easy way to get the correct answer quickly without running into the risk of double counting and/or missing some cases.  I find it odd that a "fellow" Computer Programmer "discredits" the easy simulation solution.  The OP did not ask for the code and didn't say not using  computer simulation so my solution is valid.  Your point about using computer simulation for only "hard" problems on paper is irrelevant.  It is the person's choice which method to use.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. As I've already mentioned in one of the comments above `I do not argue with the fact that for this specific question, counting all the possible combinations is a tedious and difficult task, and I certainly agree that a computer program is the correct means for solving the specific question at hand`. **I even gave a programming-based solution in my own answer**. But you justify your probabilistic solution saying it is too hard for you to come up with a deterministic solution, and that is simply a **bad excuse**.

Comment: The only reasonable excuse for a probabilistic solution, is if the computational time required for an accurate solution is extremely long. The computation time for **running this solution on a computer**, NOT the "computational time" that you require in order to think about this problem and come up with an accurate solution.

Comment: I still disagree with you.  For example, I got approximately the same answer as you (to within a few decimal places for precision).  So what difference does it make if my answer is $99.94$% as asccurate as yours but requires very little effort. Also, some computer languages are not recursive so your code (translated but still recursive) would fail in that computational environment.  My solution is not recursive so can be implemented in any general purpose language.  On a fast computer, even billions of simulations are possible in a very short amount of time.

Comment: Also, if people agreed with you and disagreed with me, why then are they not giving you points for your comments and downvoting my solution?  It is likely because they do not agree with you and/or cuz my solution is valid, just not very "mathematical".  Fast computers have made math easier cuz if someone doesn't know to and/or doesn't want to count up cases like this, they can just let the computer do the work.  Using my simulation, and exact answer will not be achieved (except maybe by luck) but who needs exact probability? An approximation in this case of $99.94$% is more than good enough.

Comment: 1. This question is not about "matching code to work on any language". 2. This question is not about programming - you can choose a programming solution, but there is certainly no requirement to make it work on every possible language. 3. No piece of code would work on every possible language in any case. 4. You didn't even post your own code which you seem to be proud of as some sort of agnostic code working in every language.

Comment: 5. `So what difference does it make if my answer is 99.94% as accurate as yours but requires very little effort?` - This is by far one of the worst excuses I've heard in a while. The purpose of questions here (and in Mathematics in general) is to obtain an **accurate solution**. True, it may not be feasible in some cases, but this is **not** one of these cases, and saying `requires very little effort` is like saying `well, I'm too lazy to think about a solution, so here is a rough estimate`. It's as if someone asks you how much is $72\cdot25$, and you say "around $2000$ is close enough".

Comment: 6. `On a fast computer, even billions of simulations are possible in a very short amount of time` - again, the problem here is not the computational time in either case. In fact, even without seeing your probabilistic solution (which you did not bother to post), it obviously takes more time than an exhaustive solution, since it has to run over large amounts of data. But again, computational time is not an issue here in either case. It's the actual time to think and come up with the correct solution that matters. And that time needs to be well spent **before answering the question**.

Comment: 7. `If people agreed with you and disagreed with me, why then are they not giving you points for your comments and downvoting my solution? It is likely because they do not agree with you and/or cuz my solution is valid, just not very "mathematical"` - wrong conclusion. This entire post (question and answers) has received very little attention in general. You can check the total number of votes here, as well as the total number of views on the question.

Comment: 8. `If someone doesn't know to and/or doesn't want to count up cases like this, they can just let the computer do the work`. **Wrong**. If someone doesn't know or doesn't want to calculate the solution, then they should simply refrain from answering this question.

Comment: 9. `Using my simulation, and exact answer will not be achieved (except maybe by luck) but who needs exact probability` - as I've already mentioned a few comments above - this is a very bad excuse no matter how you'd interpret it. In particularly, the `Who needs exact probability` part. This statement certainly speaks for itself and summarizes your general "mis-conceptual" attitude towards this question.

Comment: Barak, I think your philosophy about how to answer questions like these is "whacked".  I am not "buying" any of it.  Again with probability, an approximation that is 99.94% accurate as is mine in this case is more than good enough.  I can use whatever tools and methods are available to me to solve problems and for this problem, computer simulation is so simple and so accurate.  You seem to have a lot of excuses but like I said, I don't agree with any of them.  I also feel my code is much simpler for the average person to understand and implement in a general purpose language.

Comment: This is not an exam question where they say no calculators/computers allowed and show all work.  This question was "wide open" for any solutions.  Someone could theoretically run 100 simulations with an actual die and pencil and paper and come up with a reasonable approximation and I would accept that as a reasonable answer. To answer your question about approximating products such as 72*25, it depends on the circumstance. For example, if someone was shopping and wanted 25 items priced at 72 cents each, knowing it will be "slightly" under 20 bucks is good enough.  Exactness is at the register.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22028/discussion-between-david-and-barak-manos).